# tomcat 8 silent install on windows as service

Tags: tomcat, windows-service, tomcat8

I'd like to create installer for my application. I need to install tomcat 8 as service on windows host. Is there any possibility to install it in silent mode and provide parameters to configure ports, heapsize, ...?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

i think your best option will be doing this for installation:

C:\Backup>apache-tomcat-8.5.4.exe /S /D=C:\Backup\Tomcat

then replace the /conf/server.xml file with your customized version and then run /bin/service.bat to install the service.